# How to make an CFArrayRef to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

This is my Code to create the CFArrayRef. I want to know how to make it to an NSMutableArray. I need it for my TableViewController. Or is there another way to use the CFArrayRef in the TableViewController?

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef arrayOfAllPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `CFArrayRef` is toll-free bridged to `NSArray *`, so you can cast it as such and then create a mutable copy:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [(NSArray *) myCFArrayRef mutableCopy];
```

Comment: How about type casting NSMutableArray to CFArrayRef

Comment: If you use ARC, I think you need to use this instead: (__bridge NSArray *)

Answer (score 3):

For an autoreleased version, use

```
NSMutableArray* data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: (NSArray*) myCFArrayRef];
```