# How to convert CFArrayRef to NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an CFArrayRef to an NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761461/how-to-make-an-cfarrayref-to-an-nsmutablearray)

I know there is so many info about this questions, but every single answers are "this is easy. you can do cast as toll-free bridged.", and then there is no mention of actual source code.
I know the mean of toll-free bridged and cast. 
I wanna know the exact source code "How to convert CFArrayRef to NSArray?" .
Anyone please!!!!!!

Answer (score 40):

Well, first you have to know if you are using ARC or not, because the rules change a bit.  Next, you need to know what you actually want to do with your cast.  Do you just want to use the value, or transfer ownership?

I will assume ARC, because, IMO, all new code really should be using ARC (and ARC is where the casting problems are more prevalent).

```
CFArrayRef someArrayRef = ...;
NSArray *array = (__bridge NSArray*)someArrayRef;
```

The above code casts the CF reference to an `NSArray*` that can be used in the current context.  No transfer of ownership has taken place.  `someArrayRef` still holds its reference, and you still must manually release `someArrayRef` or it will leak.

```
CFArrayRef someArrayRef = ...;
NSArray *array = CFBridgingRelease(someArrayRef);
```

In this code, you not only get a cast, but a transfer of ownership.  `someArrayRef` now no longer holds the reference, so it does not need to be manually released.  Instead, when `array` releases, the object will dealloc (assuming no other references in other places).

Comment: Looks like CFBridgingRelease is the way to go in ARC enviroment. Always transfer to NS... and uses CFBridgingRelease

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to cast it:

```
CFArrayRef *myLegacyArray = ...

...

NSArray *myArray=[(NSArray *)myLegacyArray copy];
```

Comment: You don't need to copy it. A toll-free bridge cast is literally just `NSArray* myNsArray = (NSArray*) myCfArray;`

Comment: That only works for non-ARC code.