# BButton & CGGradient release - memory leaks

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I am using BButton (https://github.com/jessesquires/BButton) to draw some nice looking buttons in cells within a UICollectionView. When I refresh the UICollectionView's data, I record some memory leaks (one leaked object per cell in the CollectionView).  I have traced this back using instruments to a CGGradient that is created in 'BButton.m':

```
gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef)newGradientColors, newGradientLocations);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

I am aware that CGGradients should be released ( CGGradientRelease() ), however I am not sure where exactly to release this, I have tried a few locations (after the button is drawn, before the return in the init methods) but I still get the same issue.

Everything is done in IB, the buttons & cells are not created programatically.

Any help would be appreciated, I am close to tearing my hair out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using ARC. And if you are I think your problem is your CFArrayRef not transferring ownership. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285231/how-to-convert-cfarrayref-to-nsarray) so I don't need to duplicate what I mean.

Comment: Can you post your solution, please?